# PHP return success even when no record is inserted in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this php code to insert new record in database. The problem is that `if ($query)` sometimes returns **true** and when I check the table, there is no new record. Why is it not inserting the record? and why is it returning true when it should return false in case of failing?

```
public function insertUserMileage($alias, $address, $distance, $city,
        $latitude, $longitude, $id) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user_mileage (user_id, alias, address, distance,
        city, lat, lng) VALUES (:id, :alias, :address, :distance, :city,
          :latitude, :longitude)';
    $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':alias' => $alias,
        ':address' => $address, ':distance' => $distance, ':city' => $city,
        ':latitude' => $latitude, ':longitude' => $longitude));
    if ($query) {
        return true;  // Insert success
    } else {
        return false; // Insert fail
    }
}
```

Comment: wrap the if statement around the `execute()` statement.

Comment: vote to close as typo

Comment: You are checking the wrong condition. `if ($query)` evaluates `$query` as `TRUE` because `$this->conn->prepare($sql)` succeeded and returned an object (which is never `FALSE`). You should check the value returned by `$query->execute()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the return value of execute:

```
$result = $query->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':alias' => $alias,
    ':address' => $address, ':distance' => $distance, ':city' => $city,
    ':latitude' => $latitude, ':longitude' => $longitude));
if ($result) {
    return true;  // Insert success
} else {
    return false; // Insert fail
}
```